# Status Code:500 Internal Server Error, while calling a webmethod in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, web-services, ajax, c-sharp

I am trying to call a webmethod written on application page but getting an error,

> Status Code:500 Internal Server Error

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "SiteUrl/_layouts/15/SharepointProject1/WebMethods.aspx/Hello",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         async: true,
         success: function (msg) {
    alert(msg.d);
             response(msg.d);

         },
         error: function (xhr, status, error) {
              alert(xhr.status);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
         }
     });
    });
</script>
```

C# Code:

```
 public partial class WebMethods : UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase
    {

        protected override bool AllowAnonymousAccess { get { return true; } }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static string Hello()
        {
            return "Hello External";
        }

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
       public static string GetDate()
       {
           return DateTime.Now.ToString();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues

1. Person class should be set as Serializable
2. GetDate method accepts 0 parameters but you are passing two values from the Ajax call.

**Sample Service**

```
public partial class Services : LayoutsPageBase
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static string Hello()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

**Sample Ajax Call**

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/projectfolder/services.aspx/Hello";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",     
    dataType: "json",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (data, arg) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: I have modified the code but getting the same error,can you please check now?

Comment: Check my sample

Comment: Hi,Getting below error


{Message: "There was an error processing the request.", StackTrace: "", ExceptionType: ""}
ExceptionType
:
""
Message
:
"There was an error processing the request."
StackTrace
:
""

Comment: Today I have tried with my old code and found it's working fine,now I am trying to find what's the reason of this different behaviour?